# Showing Return value of function "True/false" on OnBeforeUnload

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, dom-events

I am calling a function on OnBeforeUnload and returning true/false. When I am going to close the browser, the browser displays the message "Are You Sure You want to navigate away from this page", below this it is written "True/False".

Code is like :-

```
<body   onbeforeunload="javascript:return unlockOperationon()">
</body>
```

And JavaScript Function Is:-

```
function unlockOperationon()
{
    return true;
}
```

Comment: When I close the browser,i have to perofrm some server side functions.

if any exception comes in these server side function,i have to show an alert message that "Operation Unsuccessful" and in that case browser should not be closed.

else close the browser.

Answer (score 2):

you need to return "True/False" string from the unlockOperationonMain method. Purpose of the `onbeforeunload` is to ask user with meaningful message so handler of this message used to get that message. For example you may return from handler this string: "All unsaved changes on this page will be lost."

Here is an implementation of idea proposed in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12929152/showing-return-value-of-function-true-false-on-onbeforeunload/12930149#comment17552914_12930149):

```
<script runat="server" >
     [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
     public static string GetBeforeUnloadMessage()
     {
          return DateTime.Now.Second < 30 ? "Please, stay with us at least for a few seconds." : null;
     }
</script>
<head runat="server">
     <title></title>
     <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript">
          function checkServerBeforeUnload() {
               var result = null;
               $.ajax({
                    url: location.href + "/GetBeforeUnloadMessage",
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    async: false,
                    success: function (response) {
                         result = response.d;
                    }
               });

               if (result) {
                    return result;
               }
          }
     </script>
</head>
<body onbeforeunload="return checkServerBeforeUnload()">
     <form id="form1" runat="server">
     <div>
          Page rendered at:
          <%= DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss") %>
          <asp:Button runat="server" Text="Click Me" />
     </div>
     </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just an extra note, nothing to contradict your answer: web pages don't get to tell the user that the user must not close them. They only get to inform the user why the user might not want to close them, but if the user still wants to close the web page, it will be closed, there isn't and shouldn't be any way to stop that.

Comment: When I close the browser,i have to perofrm some server side functions.

if any exception comes in these server side function,i have to show an alert message that "Operation Unsuccessful" and in that case browser should not be closed.

else close the browser.

Comment: @Devesh, you can't prevent user from close browser. Just deal with it. If you need some server-side check before user close browser, you may do synchronous async call to server, performs checks you need and in case you believe that browser shouldn't be closed return message to explain user why he must stay on this page